# mysqli fetch_all() not a valid function?

Tags: php, mysqli

Thanks to the answers I have figured out that I am unable to use `fetch_all()` because i am using `PHP 5.2.17` - `fetch_assoc` with `while` loop worked.

---

The function I am using `fetch_all` is coming back with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
$query = "LONG QUERY that works, tested in phpmyadmin"
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$result->fetch_all(); or  $mysqli->fetch_all() tried both
mysqli_fetch_all() was already tried.
$mysqli->close();
```

I am able to connect to the DB and I have pulled single rows. When I place the query in PHPMYADMIN I get 5 rows back.

Does this function even work? Is there a way I can place my data into an assoc array on my own?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This function is available since PHP 5.3.0. Possibly your version is older. Use `fetch_assoc()` instead.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do what you need.
}
```

Answer (score 35):

`mysqli::fetch_all()` needs `mysqlnd` driver to be installed before you can use it.

Comment: Yes, and if you have a roundcube running (on Debian)  it will stop working since mysqlnd removes php-mdb2-driver-mysql and roundcube-mysql driver. So install mysqlnd with caution

Answer (score 22):

Issue seems to be 'mysqli' and 'mysqlnd' are not working together. I had the same issue in cpanel

Steps:

1) Go to CPanel dashboard

2) Go to 'Select PHP Version', you should see a bunch of checkboxes

3) Set PHP version (5.4 or above)

4) Uncheck the 'mysqli' extension and check both 'mysqlind' and 'nd_mysqli'

Apparently 'nd_mysqli' is 'mysqli' but configured to work with 'mysqlind' and to make it work you have to uncheck 'mysqli' due to settings conflicts.

Following answer I found [here](https://www.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/mysqli-and-mysqlnd-dont-work-together/m-p/127397#M7658) helped me.

Comment: this is the correct answer. it's not about the PHP version, but about the extension. must be nd_mysqli and mysqlind. my hosting pre-select mysqli and nd_mysqli, that's why mysqli_fetch_all does not work.

Comment: Correct answer! Thanks a lot, I do not know why this happened but it helped me ^^

Comment: Correct! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Don't just change this setting on a whim, it can have serious implications. Doing so took down my site until I reverted the changes.

Comment: corect thanks alot it worked for me as well

Answer (score 21):

The typical way to construct an associative array is in a `while` loop:

```
$results_array = array();
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $results_array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: This code helped me solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Please be careful about using fetch_all():

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#88031

Read the note about mysqldn requirement.

Comment: Couldn't find anything about the mysqldn requirement on that page. Could you elaborate, why fetch_all() is "evil"? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

As an addition to Fabrizios answer, please consider building up your array with a loop:

```
$array = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    $array[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to iterate using **[Karolis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6694641/7436256)**' answer,
use

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
       $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

to achieve the same result as

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

You may change constant to `MYSQLI_NUM` or `MYSQLI_BOTH`.
This optional parameter are  constants indicating what type of array should be produced from the current row data.

Notice that `mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC )` behaves identically to the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function, while `mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)` will behave identically to the `mysqli_fetch_row()` function. The final option `MYSQLI_BOTH` will create a single array with the attributes of both.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: This answer is essentially wrong.  `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` **does not** achieve the same result as
`$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: It's funny I didn't notice that. Grateful @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 2):

I had 5.6 but didn't work for me anyway. By enabling the mysqlnd driver it worked for me. Just write `apt-get install php5-mysqlnd` then restart php and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);//not work
```

change to:php 5.3 or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_counter` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20";
$result =  mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die
("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
$rows = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an additional note about the `mysqlnd` driver: It also has to have the `mysqli` API extension installed. Without the extension, `fetch_all()` still won't be available. I found this while troubleshooting why my code worked on one server but not another, both PHP > 5.3. Use `phpinfo()` to verify the installed extensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
                $resultset  = array(); //you need to define array
                         while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                              $resultset[] = $row; //then insert result into the array
            }       
            if(!empty($resultset))
            {

            return $resultset;}
            else{return 'empty';};
    }
```