# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysqli, fetchall, mysqlnd

I have problems with PHP in Ubuntu 10.04. When I try use mysqli_result::fetch_all this error appears:

**Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()**

However, it works in Windows XP.

The Code:

```
$result = $this->dbh->query('SELECT [...] ');
return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I don't want to use **fetch_assoc** with a loop because I send the result to another layer for processing.

I'm using PHP 5.4.4. and with **php -m | grep mysql** the mysqlnd module it doesn't appear. How can I install it? Could that be the problem?

Comment: When you say that it "works" on a different platform - do you mean two separate installations of PHP and MySql?  Or are you referring to the browser?

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677161/3571603). https://stackoverflow.com/a/56677161/3571603

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> mysqli_result::fetch_all() requires MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd).

chances are you might be missing it.

have a look at this posts, that might help you.

[mysqli fetch_all() not a valid function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694437/mysqli-fetch-all-not-a-valid-function)

Comment: Ubuntu users can just do: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`

Comment: @Ibrahim, [Where to download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result#comment50239420_8343970) ?

Comment: @Pacerier, what OS are you using?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, Win server 2003.

Comment: Try enabling mysqlnd extension, follow the link here for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158943/install-both-mysql-and-mysqlnd-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: here are few more link for your reference, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php, https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/, unfortunately i do not use windows and hence cannot test, if this does not work, try upgrading your php version it may work.

Answer (score 4):

`fetch_all` consumes more memory than fetch_array() and has other detrimental side effects, so instead of fixing `fetch_all`, **it's better to use `fetch_array` or `fetch_assoc`**.

Detailed from PHP documentation:

> Available only with mysqlnd.
>
> As mysqli_fetch_all() returns all the rows as an array in a single
> step, it may consume more memory than some similar functions such as
> mysqli_fetch_array(), which only returns one row at a time from the
> result set. Further, if you need to iterate over the result set, you
> will need a looping construct that will further impact performance.
> For these reasons mysqli_fetch_all() should only be used in those
> situations where the fetched result set will be sent to another layer
> for processing.

If you really want to use it, you have to install mySQL with native drive (mysqlnd)
Example installation:

```
./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
```

On Ubuntu you can just do

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Comment: But where is your answer to the question?

Comment: This must be a comment

Answer (score 3):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

> Available only with mysqlnd.

Notes about enabling `mysqlnd`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php