# Use of MySQLi within a class

Tags: php, mysqli

```
function __construct(mysqli $db, $country = NULL, $sport = NULL) {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->country = base64_decode($country);
    $this->sport = base64_decode($sport);
}

public function GetColor($colorcode) {
    $query = 'SELECT naam_nl FROM colors WHERE code = $colorcode';
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // Line 21
        echo $row['naam_nl'];
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Gives me:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/cloud/public/td/teamdresser.class.php on line 21
```

So I tried:

```
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    while ($row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['naam_nl'];
    }
```

And then...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc() in /home/cloud/public/td/teamdresser.class.php on line 21
```

I'm doing something wrong.. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The point is just that your query returns something else then a mysqli_result object. Probably `false`. - Is the `color`field a numeric value? If it isn't you missed the quotes in the query

Comment: Do some error checking. Your query is failing. Check the return value of `$this->db->query($query)`, and if it's `false` check `$this->db->error` for the error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli\_result::fetch\_all()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664536/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-resultfetch-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments say, you need to do some error checking:

```
public function GetColor($colorcode) {
    $query = 'SELECT naam_nl FROM colors WHERE code = $colorcode';
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($result === false) {
        // Throw or handle an error here
    } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // Line 21
            echo $row['naam_nl'];
        }
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

Additionally, you need the mysqlnd drivers: [Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664536/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-resultfetch-all)

Comment: I know, but the query isn't failing.. It's the `fetch_assoc`.. Still have the following error using your script: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc() in /home/cloud/public/td/teamdresser.class.php on line 21`

Comment: This might be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664536/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-resultfetch-all

Answer (score 1):

This part is wrong:

```
public function GetColor($colorcode) {
    $query = 'SELECT naam_nl FROM colors WHERE code = $colorcode';
```

PHP won't interpolate `$colorcode` when using single quotes. Use double quotes intead:

```
$query = "SELECT naam_nl FROM colors WHERE code = $colorcode";
```

**Comments**:

- Always check for the return value! That makes spotting errors much easier.
- Why don't you use prepared statements?

Comment: Edited it, but still same error code. It's the `fetch_assoc` and not the query itself.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting It *is* the query. Due to its fail, `fetch_assoc` will be "called on a non-object". Please include a `var_dump($result)` right after `$this->db->query`.