# install both mysql and mysqlnd on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I am having server at digital ocean and trying to run a custom php application. On my development machine:
Mac OSX 10.7.5
PHP: 5.3.6
with mysql, mysqli, mysqlnd, pdo mysql

But on the server:
Ubuntu 12.04
PHP: 5.3.10

with mysql, mysqli and pdo mysql

I require mysqlnd to run my app. If i try

```
apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

it is giving error:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
php5-mysql
The following NEW packages will be installed:
php5-mysqlnd
```

If I install it, my app code breaks as it uses many mysqli commands.

I searched and followed many stackoverflow question on same topic but all in vain.
Though, I haven't tried configuration option

```
./configure --with-mysql=mysqlnd \
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
```

I dont know how to proceed with this and I could not find and tutorials or article on this.

How My development machine has both but server couldn't.

Please guide.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably need to enable the `mysqlnd` extension.  I ran into this problem recently (all references `mysqli` were broken after installing `php5-mysqlnd`), and fixed it by adding the following line to the bottom of my php.ini:

```
extension=mysqlnd.so
```

You can find the location of your php.ini in the output of [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Also note you'll need to restart your webserver for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the "current" way of doing this is to enable that PHP module after you install it, much the way you do with an Apache module: `sudo php5enmod mysqlnd`

And then restart Apache for that module to load: `sudo service apache2 restart`

That will create a symlink on `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` from `/etc/php5/mods-available/` that Apache will pick up and load with priorities, like services during start-up. In my experience on Ubuntu 14 LTS it creates a symlink called *10-mysqlnd.ini* from *mysqlnd.ini*.

Here is a link for a [more detailed explanation](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/managing-php-5-4-extensions-on-ubuntu) on the subject.