# Error installing mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I was told to install mysqlnd by running sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd. However, I seem to have received an error. Any idea what's going on and how I can fix it? I'm running Ubuntu Server.

```
zerg@server:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
php5-mysql
The following NEW packages will be installed: php5-mysqlnd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 134 kB of archives.
After this operation, 247 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe php5-        mysqlnd amd64 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe php5-mysqlnd amd64 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php5/php5-mysqlnd_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
zerg@server:~$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED: php5-mysql
The following NEW packages will be installed:
php5-mysqlnd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 134 kB of archives.
After this operation, 247 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe php5- mysqlnd amd64 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe php5-mysqlnd amd64 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14
404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
(Reading database ... 28529 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5-mysql (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) ...
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module mysql for fpm SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module mysqli for fpm SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module mysqli for cli SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module pdo_mysql for fpm SAPI
php5_invoke prerm: Disable module pdo_mysql for cli SAPI
Processing triggers for php5-fpm (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) ...
php5-fpm stop/waiting
php5-fpm start/running, process 17187
E: Failed to fetch     http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php5/php5-mysqlnd_5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
```

Comment: [This link will helpfull for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158943/install-both-mysql-and-mysqlnd-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Did you update the package list?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman thanks that will help after I figure out why I'm getting the Errs.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I don't think so. Is it just sudo apt-get update?