# After install of php5-mysqlnd: MySQL server has gone away + crazy amount of connections

Tags: mysqli, php-5.5

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23
MySQL '5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'

After installing php5-mysqlnd, the SQL server doesn't maintain a connection with apache2.

Installed using the following steps

`sudo apt-get remove php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart`

In phpinfo() I get the following information under mysqlnd

`active_connections 18446744073709551613
active_persistent_connections   18446744073709551613`
All other information from that table is zero, except for bytes_received which is 95

Under mysqli, i get the following

`Client API library version mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev 
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On`

Basically it seems the connection is timing out, but the number of connections is weird in phpinfo();

I also tried adding `extension=mysqlnd.so` to php.ini as per this post:

[install both mysql and mysqlnd on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158943/install-both-mysql-and-mysqlnd-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score -1):

First You Remove The Program(ie Apache,Sql,And Php And Its Modules) and Then Start Again To Install, Because Some It Occurs.
Do It.