# PHP mysqli_fetch_array gets a general Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have to use a php function to manage some data from a db, but i get a Fatal Error on the line where I call mysqli_fetch_array().

```
    $request = "SELECT Post.* FROM Post WHERE IdUseFk = '".$user_idPk."';";
    $result  = mysqli_query($CONN, $request)
        or die ("<font color='red'>Error: ".mysqli_error($CONN)."</font>");
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num == 0) {echo "NOTHING TO DO HERE";}
    else
    {    
        for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);  //<<-- ERROR ON THIS LINE

            /*...Some other code...*/
        }

    }
```

I get this: Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\load_data.php on line 137

Any suggestion?

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

I can't believe it. For some reason the 'space' chars I put before and after the '=' char in `$row = mysqli_fetch_array()`

weren't  real spaces but another special char that is blank in most editors but php read as part of the function name. I was able to see it thanks to the editor in cpanel. Now it works

Comment: What is line 137 in load_data.php ?

Comment: Your question gives no insights into what the actual issue is. The code you have is right. A more likely scenario is that you have something up with your setup or some other code. Attach a debugger and post your log.

Comment: I've found this in the xampp php error log: 

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  mysqli_fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work\load_data.php on line 137. 

I am a bit scared now o.o

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?  I can't imagine mysqli_fetch_array being missing and mysqli_query not...

Comment: Have a look at this posts, that may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664536/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-resultfetch-all

Comment: @RizaldiMaulidia, that is only fetch_all that requires mysqlnd.  fetch_array shouldn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while loop, and you also had an error in your SQL syntax.

```
$request = "SELECT Post.* FROM Post WHERE IdUseFk = '$user_idPk'";
$result = mysqli_query($CONN, $request)
     or die ("<font color='red'>Error: ".mysqli_error($CONN)."</font>");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num == 0) { 
        echo "NOTHING TO DO HERE";
    }  else {    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) {
           /*...Some other code...*/     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try again with my edit. I think you had a syntax error in your query.

Comment: And ditch the for loop, the while loop will loop through however many rows you are retrieving in your query.

Comment: This isn't the issue.  The while loop is unnecessary.  Either way would work fine.  The issue is something with their PHP install if you see the error undefined function mysqli_fetch_array.