# php string comparison search only returning one entry not returning correct entries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm using ajax to send a search string to a php script that executes a mysql like function to find all related entries with the username like the string being sent for friend searching. I have two current entries in the database zukeru and zukeru2. when i search z i only get zukeru returned in my console output. When i search 2 i still get zukeru and im really not sure why.

Also how to i remove a specific field from a php nested tupple. I don't want to include the password field for obvious reason. Sorry im new to php learning as i go so far its not as bad as I thought it would be kinda similar to python.

returned object when searching the number 2, but i get zukeru and not zukeru2 doesn't make sense.

```
Object {0: "2", 1: "you wish you could see", 2: "zukeru", 3: "deleted for security", 4: "grant", id: "2", email: "deleted for security", username: "zukeru", password: "deleted for security", name: "grant"}
```

this is the search string i used for the above result. You can see i searched 2 and got back zukeru and not zukeru2

```
profile.php:92 searchstring=2

<?php 
    $db = new mysqli(security reasons removed.);
    extract($_POST);
    //I think i can remove this session start ?
    session_start();
    $serach_string = $_POST['searchstring'];
    $fetch=$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$serach_string%'");
    $friends=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);
    //echo $search_string
    echo json_encode($friends);
?>
```

Here is my jquery incase you wanted to see

```
  function search(){
        var url = "search_friends.php";       
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
              url: url,
               data: $("#search_friends").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                 success: function(data)
                   {   
                    //console.log(data);       
                     var returned_friends = JSON.parse(data); 
                     var html_built = '<br>';
                     console.log(returned_friends);
                     console.log($("#search_friends").serialize());
                     if (returned_friends){ 
                         $.each( returned_friends, function( key, value ) {
                            if (key =="username"){
                                html_built += '<li><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;" id="'+value+'" onClick="add_friend(this.id)"> Send '+value+' A Friend Request</button></li>';
                            }
                         });
                    }
                    html_built += ""
                     document.getElementById("list_friends").innerHTML = html_built;  

                   }
               });
        return false;
  }
```

this is what im currently using and I get undefined method. It cant find fetch_all(); and im using php 5.4

here is the console error returned.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in <b>/home/gzukel/public_html/search_friends.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

<?php 
    $db = new mysqli();
    extract($_POST);
    session_start();
    $serach_string = $_POST['searchstring'];
    if($fetch=$db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$serach_string%'")){
       $friends=$fetch->fetch_all();
       echo json_encode($friends);
    }else{
       echo 'no results';
    }
?>
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php - the fetch functions return a single ROW of results, not the entire result set.

Comment: so what would be the best way to return a result set ? What would be the standard common practice way?

Comment: fetch in a loop, build array, then encode the array

Comment: so something like I posted below @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

so something like this?

```
<?php 
    $db = new mysqli();
    extract($_POST);
    session_start();
    $serach_string = $_POST['searchstring'];
    $fetch=$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$serach_string%'");
    $friends=[]

    while($row = $fetch->fetch_array())
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        array_push($friends,$row['username']);   
    }
    //echo $search_string
    echo json_encode($friends);
?>
```

Comment: if you only need the friends names, then don't `select *`. that's a waste of cpu/database time. just `select username` and build one single array.

Answer (score 0):

You Could use [fetch all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
if($fetch=$db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$serach_string%'")){

   $friends= $fetch->fetch_all();

   echo json_encode($friends);
}else{
   echo 'no results';
}
```

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in <b>/home/gzukel/public_html/search_friends.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Comment: using fetch all returns undefined @andrew

Comment: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) should return as mysqli result object, if not the query or connection is wrong, ill edit the above to show how to check for that

Comment: @GrantZukel u r probably using php < 5.3.0, note that I am not the andrew who answered your post

Comment: @Andrew ah yes, the manul says (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0), I didn't know that, thanks

Comment: im using php 5.4 @Andrew

Comment: This post "might" help u, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664536/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-resultfetch-all