# mysqli_fetch_all stopped working on PHP 5.4.11

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a basic site with a host and as of recent the `mysqli_fetch_all` command has appeared to have stopped working as I receive the message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in file at line where function is used
```

I rolled back the files on the server to a set that I know work and yet I run into the same issue even though the page is running `PHP5.4+`.

I cannot figure out why this has suddenly stopped working. Offline, using XAMPP, the mysqli_fetch_all command works perfectly and therefore the issue doesn't seem to be with the DB or the code. I would prefer not to rewrite numerous pages with a while loop for an unknown reason.

Is this an issue with the server host? Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: whats the php version of XAMPP? This might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694437/mysqli-fetch-all-not-a-valid-function

Comment: XAMPP is running 5.4.7 whereas the host is running 5.4.11 retrieved using phpversion()
As the function should be fine with PHP 5.3+ this behaviour seems unusual.

Comment: The function is only available with the mysqlnd driver. The host may be using the older mysql driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways the MySQLi extension may be compiled:

1. By linking it against MySQL's client library
2. By compiling against the MySQL Native Driver that is bundled with php (mysqlnd)

`mysqli_fetch_all()` is only available in the second case, see http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_all

I would recommend to avoid such mysqlnd-only functions for compatibility reasons. If compatibility is not an issue for you and you desperately need this function, you have to recompile php `--with-mysqli=mysqlnd`.

Comment: I would recommend to avoid such an uncertain extension and move to PDO

Comment: Thanks for the help - a server upgrade has removed the functionality of the command so I'm using a more compatible loop to do the same job.