# Call to a member function query() on a non-object error

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, I took out all the functions to eliminate out of scope variables and am now getting an error on the last line. " Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()"

```
    $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `$conn` is out of scope in your function.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I've updated the question. THe problem still remains.

Comment: @thinkofacard - it's still out of scope in `test()`.

Comment: Ah. But it's still not working. I eliminated all the functions to eliminate out of scope problem. Now I get an error on the last line, " Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()"

Comment: I think I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694437/mysqli-fetch-all-not-a-valid-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any idea why I'm getting this error when the $result = $conn->query($sql); tries to run??

You should read this [part of documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You can't use `$conn` variable inside function like that. All variables used inside function must be either passed as arguments or declared in function body.

tldr: Just move `$conn = test_connect();` into body of function `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in below code:

function test() {$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; $result = $conn->query($sql); return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); }

You should define $conn object as global in test function or pass this in function.

Try below code:

function test() {
global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; $result = $conn->query($sql); return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); }

OR

function test($conn) {$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; $result = $conn->query($sql); return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); }