# Save SQL data to PHP array

Tags: php, sql, fetchall

I want to pull the data from a SQL table to an array in my PHP script. I need that because after that I want to compare two tables.

```
$sql = "select date, sum(clicks) from Table group by date";

$query = $Db->query($sql);

$result = array(); // Script does not work even if I remove this line

$result = $query->fetchAll();

print_r($result);
```

I am getting the error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll()

Comment: `$result = $query->fetch_all();` [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli fetch\_all() not a valid function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694437/mysqli-fetch-all-not-a-valid-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark said, use

```
$result = $query->fetch_all();
```

For PHP version prior to PHP 5.3.0, use:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do what you need.
}
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Comment: I've edited the response. Please also post your PHP version.