# PHP array_push() doesn't work but array[] does, only without SQL where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

So I have a very odd problem I came across while using SQL clauses and PHP commands. For some reason my code works fine when using the command
`"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName=text";`
But doesn't work when using
        `"SELECT * FROM tableName";`
I've put the SQL command directly into MySQL, and it returns results. If I implode the row array, I get the results, and if I switch from using
        `array_push($result...)`
to
        `$result= []`
I get the last entry in JSON format, as expected. I'm not sure why I'm getting this behavior, this code I believe worked in a previous version of PHP, or maybe an older version of MySQL. I've done some updates recently and everything is now at the very latest version. Searching found people who had both array_push and array[] not work, or where the command didn't work with the WHERE clause, but I have the opposite issue. Not sure what it could be, I enabled PHP error reporting and SQL error reporting, and I just get the PHP white screen of death when the issue happens.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','dbuser');
define('PASS','dbpassword');
define('DB','dbname');

$eventYear = isset($_GET["year"]) ? $_GET["year"] : '';
$eventYear = addslashes($eventYear);
if (empty($_GET["year"])){
$eventYear = 2016;
}

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die ("Database Connection Failed");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (!$res) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('teamNumberLabel'=>'Team Number',
'teamNumber'=>$row["teamNumber"],
'teamEventLabel'=>'Team Event Name',
'teamEvent'=>$row["teamEvent"],
'teamDistrictCodeLabel'=>'District Code: ',
'teamDistrictCode'=>$row["teamDistrictCode"],
'teamCityLabel'=>'City: ',
'teamCity'=>$row["teamCity"],
'teamStateProvLabel'=>'State/Province: ',
'teamStateProv'=>$row["teamStateProv"],
'teamCountryLabel'=>'Country: ',
'teamCountry'=>$row["teamCountry"],
'teamNameFullLabel'=>'Sponsors: ',
'teamNameFull'=>$row["teamNameFull"],
'teamNameShortLabel'=>'Nickname: ',
'teamNameShort'=>$row["teamNameShort"],
'teamRobotNameLabel'=>'Name: ',
'teamRobotName'=>$row["teamName"],
'teamRookieYearLabel'=>'Rookie Year: ',
'teamRookieYear'=>$row["teamRookieYear"],
'teamWebsiteLabel'=>'Website: ',
'teamWebsite'=>$row["teamWebsite"]
));
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I have a lot of other files with similar code, but they all contain WHERE clauses on the SQL command, so it all works as expected. Just have the problem where nothing works without the WHERE clause included. I've tried placing quotes around the table name, but it shows incorrect SQL syntax, so that isn't it. Also read up on SQL commands and array_push and I can't seem to figure it out.

**Update:** As Marshall stated, I believe the issue now is data that is not in UTF-8, which causes the JSON encoding to fail and not display any data. The table is hundreds of entries long, so I'm going to filter out non UTF-8 characters before encoding to see if it works then.

**Update 2:** Found the issue. I have another script that runs through the list of teams for a single event (this one is similar but returns all teams for the entire year), and I went through the list until it failed similar to this one. A Canada event with non-UTF-8 characters is what's causing the scripts to fail. Montréal is showing as MontrÃ©al in the database and Québec as QuÃ©bec. The code worked earlier only because this event didn't exist when the code was initially tested, and the é is an unsupported character. This also explains why the code works with the WHERE clause and the array[] function, because it doesn't hit the malformed data in either case. Properly filtering the data coming in like I should've would have not caused this, but at least now I know the cause, I was really stuck on this one because the code looked correct and the SQL command was correct as well. Thanks for your help everyone.

**Update 3:** Okay so here's the full fix. I modified everything in PHPMyAdmin to the utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation, and utf8mb4 character set. Then modified the script that fetches the data from the API and enters it into the database. I'm using PDO to connect to the db, so I added the charset to the PDO entry.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8mb4", 'username', 'password');
```

That got the data going into the database correctly, but the JSON parser still didn't work. Found out I also needed to explicitly tell it to work in the UTF-8MB4 charset. Adding

```
$con->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

to the PHP script before the SQL query fixed that. Now the correct characters go through both where the data enters the database and when it is requested. So the problem was that the scripts were not set to UTF-8, when the data was coming through as such. Hopefully this helps someone with a similar problem.

Comment: Is there anything in your error logs?

Comment: Your comments and code don't match. You say you tried using `$result=array_push(...)`, but your code just says `array_push($result...`. Which is it?

Comment: what happends if you just print out whatever it gives back? maybe its slightly different from what you expect

Comment: I'm not sure you clearly stated what your problem is... However if nothing is displayed at the end of this script when selecting the whole table vs only 1 row, it may show you that the problem occurs because of the table **content**. You should try to call `echo json_last_error_msg()` after `json_encode` to see if there is a problem there. If the problem is due to non-UTF8 character in your database, you should try to convert the strings in your array before you send it to json_encode.

Comment: No, nothing in the logs, just checked again. And I meant as the code shows, array_push($result, array...) will update post. If I implode the $result array, using  implode(",", $result); before the while loop, it prints everything requested. So the SQL command does work, just not when using array_push. I was thinking maybe weird data in the table could cause that?

Comment: And yes Marshall I was just thinking non UTF-8 data may be causing it. I'm requesting the data through an API, and there's hundreds of entries.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let MySQL handle all the data manipulation..

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    'Team Number' as teamNumberLabel, 
    teamNumber,
    'Team Event Name' as teamEventLabel,
    teamEvent,
    'District Code: ' as teamDistrictCodeLabel,
    teamDistrictCode,
    'City: ' as teamCityLabel,
    teamCity,
    'State/Province: ' as teamStateProvLabel,
    teamStateProv,
    'Country: ' as teamCountryLabel,
    teamCountry,
    'Sponsors: ' as teamNameFullLabel,
    teamNameFull,
    'Nickname: ' as teamNameFull,
    teamNameShort,
    'Name: ' as teamRobotNameLabel,
    teamName as teamRobotName,
    'Rookie Year: ' as teamRookieYearLabel,
    teamRookieYear,
    'Website: ' as teamWebsiteLabel,
    teamWebsite
FROM tableName";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

Use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get all the results at once and skip the loop.

If you can't use `mysqli_fetch_all()` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694437/mysqli-fetch-all-not-a-valid-function), and do this instead:

```
// Use the query from above
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) array_push($result, $r);
```

Comment: That's probably better, but for some reason I get an undefined function error. Looked it up and the function should exist I'm on PHP 5.6.21-1. Looked it up some more, says the function may not exist if PHP was not compiled with mysqlnd, which I don't believe it was.

Comment: Changed the PHP package from php5-mysql to php5-mysqlnd and now the code runs, but I get an empty JSON reply now. Better than a white screen, I'm thinking it's just non UTF-8 data somewhere in the table as Marshall was saying. The code is better now though, so thank you.

Comment: oh well, if i helped feel free to give me a +1 :)

Comment: I did but I don't have more than 15 reputation, so the public score doesn't change. Thank you though. Trying to filter out non-utf8 characters before posting to see if that fixes things. If it does I'll modify the API parser to strip out non-utf8 characters before entering the data into the database. The API is supposed to already be filtered, but I probably shouldn't trust it.

Comment: Problem ended up being that the db needed to be switched to utf8mb4, and the scripts needed to be expressly told to run in utf8mb4 mode. Now everything works, but your edits made the code simpler and easier to read, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$row` contains all required indexes in your `array_push` function. You should validate the `$row`.

From the [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) manual:

```
Note: This function sets NULL fields to the PHP NULL value.
```